# Getting data from mysql into JSON using PHP works locally but not on server

Tags: php, mysql, json

My code works in 100% locally and returns answer looks like:

```
[{"id":"1","zuzycie":"40"},{"id":"3","zuzycie":"83.333333333333"}]
```

The same structure of files and codes are on the server. I don't have a problem with connect to database, so the path is fine. But code on the server is returning `[null,null,null,null,null]`. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

```
<?php
    //setting header to json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    require_once "../polaczenie.php";

    //get connection
    $mysqli = @new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

    if(!$mysqli){
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
    }

    //query to get data from the table
    $query = sprintf("SELECT id, zuzycie FROM zuzycie_paliwa ORDER BY id ");

    //execute query
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    //loop through the returned data
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    //free memory associated with result
    $result->close();

    //close connection
    $mysqli->close();

    //now print the data
    print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have data in your server db? `var_dump` your `$data` variable.

Comment: Yes, id = 1 and zuzycie = 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my doubts about it working locally, because you're trying to iterate through a mysqli result. Try replacing your foreach loop with

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Iterator support was added to [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) in 5.4. It probably did work in the OP's local environment because their PHP version was newer than that, and vice versa on their host's server.